# JavaScript API | JS API

Tags: javascript

If you want to search the library API of the following, you go to their respective links:

[Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/)

[nodejs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/)

[mySQL (C)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html)

Where is **THE** API for Javascript itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical one would be the ECMA-262 spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1. Keep in mind, though, that language support is not consistent across browsers. For that, there is a variety of third-party resources:

- [Quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/)
- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org)
- [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/)

Comment: The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript) is very thorough and accurate.

Comment: There's also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/yek4tbz0(v=vs.94).aspx).