# how to get value from url parameter using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue in getting value from url, I have a link which shows up a modal
as I have

```
<a href='#modal?userId=<%=resultSet.getInt("drid")%>' class="button-border toggleModal">Apportionment</a>
```

above link opens up the modal is given below

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">    
    <header>
      <h2>Appointment Form</h2>      
    </header>
    <form action="addappoinment.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" id="docId" name="docid" value=""><br>
        <input type="text" required><br>
        <input type="text" required><br>
        <input type="text" required><br>
        <input type="text" required><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="21"></textarea><br> 
        <button class="button-border button-success" type="submit">
     Done</button>

    <button class="button-border button-error pull-right toggleModal">
      Cancel</button>       
      </form>    
  </div>
```

Now I have a url like

```
http://localhost:8080/app/#modal?userId=1
```

now I want to get value of `userId` parameter using the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var param = getParameterByName("userId");
var userId = document.getElementById("docId");
userId.value = param;


</script>
```

but can not be able to get value from `http://localhost:8080/app/#modal?userId=1`

Comment: You want the `#modal` to be after the `?userId=blah` part.  More on how URLs are constructed is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386209/full-possible-url-syntax-and-grammar

Comment: The `getParameterByName` function doesn't work because the data you are looking for is in the fragment (everything after the #), not in the query string. Usually, this approach is used by single page application frameworks (e.g., AngularJS). Are you using such a framework? If so, it may provide methods to retrieve the information you need.

Answer (score 9):

> ```
> #modal?userId=1
> ```

The query string (which is sent to the server) has to go before the fragment identifier (which is handled entirely client side).

i.e.

```
?userId=1#modal
```

If you don't want to send that data to the server, then you need to read the fragment identifier (`location.hash`) and split it on the `?` to get the piece you need.

Comment: @LogicalError — If you don't know how to split a javascript string than Google can help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jquery url parser plugin](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl):

```
$.url().param('userId');
```

**EDIT:** If you have the URL in a string, you can do:

```
$.url('http://localhost:8080/app/#modal?userId=1').param('userId'); // returns '1'
```

**EDIT 2:** This works:

```
$.url($.url('http://localhost:8080/app/#modal?userId=1').fsegment(1)).param('userId')) //returns '1'
```

Comment: That parses query strings. The data isn't in a query string.

Comment: @Quentin: Fixed code.Thanks for pointing out. The '#' was causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUrlParams() {   
    var url = window.location
    var inputParam = 'DBName'//input parameter 
    var params = url.split('?');     
    var b = params[1].split('&');   
    for (i=0; i<b.length; i++){
    var c= b[i].split('=');
    if (c[0] == inputParam){
       alert(c[1]);//return the parameter value
       break;
}
```

Comment: A piece of advice: some explanations would significantly improve the quality of your answer.